# Configuring server cert with Keychain for use with Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api, ssl, https

I am just getting started experimenting with the Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript. Implementing the code at this link, substituting my own credentials (API Key and Client ID):

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

The console in Chrome Developer Tools is showing errors like the following:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://accounts.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "http://mydomain.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of
>   "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols
>   must match.

I am thinking I can correct this by implementing SSL on my site, which I have never done before.  I want to use a self-signed SSL certificate , which Google says is OK:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript

I would like to create the cert with Keychain on my Mac.  In the process of doing this, I have the opportunity to set extensions, such as Signature, Nonrepudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment and Key Agreement (More info on the extensions offered within Keychain: http://goo.gl/huaEpf .)

Only Signature is selected by default. Which extensions do I want to select for a server cert for use with Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this:
http://siber-sonic.com/mac/MailSMIME/setupMtLion.html

I think the best choice is not to set any extensions, just leave the "Include Key Usage Extension" checkbox unchecked.